# Python Text Matrix using NumPy and pandas

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matrix, pandas

I have been doing text scraping and just writing the text to a CSV file using a loop.  For example (skipping lots of code - this is just for illustration):

```
for i in range(0,numresults):
    a2 = soup.find_all('td')[0].string
    a3 = soup.find_all('td')[1].string
    file.write(str(i) + '|' + a2 + '|' + a3 + '\n')
```

Then I can open this CSV file in something like R.

But let's say that instead I want to create a matrix in python.  First of all is it best to use pandas or NumPy when using data with lots of text?

Second of all, how would I modify the code to not write to a file, but to create both a pandas and a NumPy array?

Lets say the text ends up being:

```
a11 = 1; a12 = 'a'; a13 = 'Text1'
a21 = 2; a22 = 'B'; a23 = 'Text2'
a31 = 3; a32 = 'c'; a33 = 'Text3'
a41 = 4; a42 = 'D'; a44 = 'Text4'

import numpy as np
import pandas
```

Finally, how would I then write the resulting pandas and NumPy matrices to a CSV file?

Comment: What is the format of the initial text data or the text data at the point when you want it into the pandas dataframe / numpy array? I think reading the data into a pandas dataframe, doing your text scraping, then using the to_csv method would probably be the simplest option.

Comment: The text comes from an HTML file that I read in with requests, then process with BeautifulSoup.  When I want it to go into pandas (or NumPy), it will be string.

Comment: I'm really not that familiar with BeautifulSoup but ultimately it depends on how your data is structured not just the type. If it is JSON this can be read in easily with pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using BeautifulSoup to get tables from HTML. I have successfully used Pandas to extract tables from webpages. Using example from pandas doc (Here's the [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-html)):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: tables = pd.read_html('http://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.html')
```

In this case `tables` only has one table. You can do `print tables[0]` to view or `tables[0].to_csv(local_csv_output)` to save as CSV file.
`pd.read_html` can read both URL (http...) and local HTML files.

If you have multiple tables, just manually find out which one you need by printing them.

Give it a try and let us know.

If you already have variable `a11,a11,...` assigned (which seems weird -- they should be in `list`), then you can create pandas DataFrame:

```
    In [38]: df = pd.DataFrame ([[a11,a12,a13],
[a21,a22,a23],
[a31,a32,a33],
[a41,a42,a44]],
columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3'])

In [39]: df
Out[39]: 
   Col1 Col2   Col3
0     1    a  Text1
1     2    B  Text2
2     3    c  Text3
3     4    D  Text4
```

And `df.to_csv('output_csv_file.csv')` will save it to csv.

Comment: Unfortunately, my web scraping stuff is more involved than just finding tables.  I just did a simple example in my question.  Plus, I already know BeautifulSoup, so would rather just use that to get my data and then put it into pandas.